# Problem with the installation on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, gpt

I had a computer running Windows7 and wanted to change to Ubuntu.

So I installed the 14.04 LTS version and all seemed to have gone cool. (I'd like to make clear that I want just Ubuntu in the computer, not a dual boot with windows). Finished installation and system asked to reboot to start from hard drive (installation made via a Live CD).

The problem comes when I see that no grub is loaded, laptop doesn't do anything just ask whether to boot from hard drive or CD, if you press HDD doesn't load anything, just asks the same. It seems that I have a problem in the boot partition?

When I load the live CD and get to the terminal, I type `fdisk -l` to see my partitions and this is the answer I get :

```
"WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted."
```

Tried to install grub from terminal but this answer appears:

"grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'."

I have 4 partitions, boot, home, root and swap. Which has to be the format of the boot? Efi, ext2, fat...?

Has anything to do with the previous windows installation and thus, some conflict with the master boot record and the format that Windows 7 uses?

So i have no idea how to solve this. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: GPT is used on BIOS-mode installations when the disk is over 2TiB in size and on EFI-mode installations no matter what the disk's size. Knowing which you've got is critical to the fix. Try running the [Boot Info Script,](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) posting the `RESULTS.txt` file it generates to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and posting the URL to your document here.